# Is it possible to add a new data on Django Object in view?

Tags: django

My question is only to ask if this is possible. For example this QuerySet in view:

```
item_list = ItemList.objects.all()
```

Inside item_list, I want to add an HTML tag to be rendered to template.

```
html_var = "<div> SOMETHING </div>"
item_list = item_list + html_var or something
```

Reason:

I want to control what type of html tag based on the index of the item_list. My first option was to use modulus on loop counter but based on docs and other's comment, we can't get the remainder on the modulus operator. The return is a boolean. If you have other suggestion instead please let me know.

**EDIT**

As per @Abdul Aziz Barkat's suggestion, I used cycle on my class. However I want to add on left the top and bottom then right the top and bottom.

Currently this is how I did it:

```
{% for job in item_list %}
<div class="{% cycle 'left' 'left' 'right' 'right' %}">
    <div class="{% cycle 'top' 'bottom' %}">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But the result becomes:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I wish to achieve:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="item">
                <p>{{job.job_title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`cycle` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'upper-left' 'lower-left' 'upper-right' 'lower-right' %}">
        content here
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This will cause each of the arguments to be used alternatively in a cycle.

Comment: I have heard of cycle and this is a promising suggestion. I will try.

Comment: Can I use if cycle? For example, cycle 1, 2 , 3, 4
if cycle == 1 or cycle == 2 ?

Comment: @rodjames can you enumerate the reason?

Comment: If cycle == 1 or cycle == 2, left else right

Comment: @rodjames why not simply use something like `{% cycle 'left' 'left' 'right' 'right' %}`?

Comment: On my left, there is Top and Bottom, on right, another set of Top and Bottom.

Comment: I updated my question. The result of @Abdul's suggestion and what I wish to achieve.